# NoSQL and SQL databases together

Tags: mysql, nosql

I couldn't find any topic with my question, so I created my own question.

I have a web application with big database which has not lot's of `Update` and `Insert` but has so many search (`Select`).

This application uses MySQL but as there are some tables which be better to be implemented by NoSQL database, so I want to change the database and convert the data to NoSQL database, but I know that it's cause problem in term of speed, when the users search into the database.

**My Question**: Is there any way to use SQL database not NoSQL database for almost all the data, but for some columns NoSQL?

Simply saying, about 85% of the database columns are fix but there are some columns who are not fix and they are related to the the record, ex: if the current record is **bird**, we need a column **can_fly** but if it's a **quadruped**, we need the column **is_mammal**.

Thanks

Comment: MySQL 's 8 document store can use a "NoSQL" interface and act like a "NoSQL" JSON Document Store  .. but MySQL 8 cheats a bit as under the hood you are using  a InnoDB with JSON datatype... Funny and good timing as i just read a few hours ago that MySQL 8.0.17+ can also natively index  a JSON array now -> see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html) section *"Multi-Valued Indexes"* for the single JSON datatype would still possible mean using a generated column and index that as i not jet have had the time it toy around this new feature i am not sure..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the answer and link. Do you think if exists any free DBMS?

Comment: in general it is hard to suggest something if we did dont know the data or user case.. Be aware programming cross database transactions can become very tricky if you want to run a MySQL and have a NoSQL besides that.. As the application needs to check if both systems committed correctly, if one got a error and the other didn't you need to "rollback" with a delete..